# sqlite select hard coded text given a matching "or" condition

Tags: sql, sqlite, relational-database

I have a table like this:

```
key,c1,c2,c3,...
--------------
key1,v1,v2,v3, ...
.....
keyn,vn,,,,,...
```

I am querying for column values whose length is 0 using a statement like this:

`SELECT key FROM table WHERE length(c1) = 0 OR length(c2) = 0 OR ... OR length(cn) = 0;`

I'd like to have a text associated with the key indicating which condition lead to the match. so something like

```
SELECT key,"column 1 length is zero" OR "column 2 length is zero"  ... OR "column N length is zero" FROM table WHERE length(c1) = 0 or length(c2) = 0 or ... or length(cn) = 0;
```

not sure how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` expression for this. On the other hand, note that in SQLite you can use `MIN()` to simplify the `WHERE` clause:

```
select 
    key,
    case 
        when length(c1) = 0 then 'column 1'
        when length(c2) = 0 then 'column 2'
        when length(c3) = 0 then 'column 3'
    end || ' is length 0' which
from mytable
where min(length(c1), length(c2), length(c3)) = 0
```

Comment: Not very DRY to repeat all the calls to length().  Doesn't matter a lot with short functions like `LENGTH(c1) = 0`, but can matter in more involved examples...

Comment: @MatBailie: I don't know about SQLite exactly, but I would expect some databases to optimize away the repeated calls.

Comment: I don't mean performance wise, I just mean Don't Repeat Yourself as a maintenance principle.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT key, 
       CASE 
          WHEN length(c1) = 0 THEN 'column 1 length is zero'
          WHEN length(c2) = 0 THEN 'column 2 length is zero'
          ...
          WHEN length(cn) = 0 THEN 'column n length is zero'
       END AS stringLen
    FROM table
    WHERE length(c1) = 0 or length(c2) = 0 or ... or length(cn) = 0;
```

With this select you can have the description of which kind of condition have the key
Hope it will be usefull

Comment: Not very DRY...  Doesn't matter a lot with short functions like `LENGTH(c1) = 0`, but can matter in more involved examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `group_concat()` in case there are more than 1 columns in the same row with length = 0:

```
select t.key, group_concat('column ' || nr || ' length is zero') result
from (
  select key, 1 nr, col1 col from tablename
  union all
  select key, 2 nr, col2 from tablename
  union all
  select key, 3 nr, col3 from tablename
) t
where length(t.col) = 0
group by t.key
```

Replace `col1`, `col2`, `col3`,... with the actual column names of your table. 
See a simplified [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5bYWmmDwDp4xRYxjiTiz2j/0).

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you can't, not all in the same scope.

What you can do is create a new column with a value that you then use in both your `WHERE` clause and the `SELECT`...

```
SELECT
  key,
  'column ' || CAST(first_empty_column_id AS TEXT) || ' length is zero'   AS message
FROM
(
  SELECT
    key,
    CASE
      WHEN LENGTH(c1) = 0 THEN 1
      WHEN LENGTH(c2) = 0 THEN 2
      ...
      WHEN LENGTH(cn) = 0 THEN n
    END
      AS first_empty_column_id
  FROM
    table
)
  checked_table
WHERE
  first_empty_column_id IS NOT NULL
```